# Why I was confused "the exit status code is 0 when a command fails in BASH"

Tags: c, bash

**NOTE:** This question is not asked in the right way. The reason is that the `!` in the condition line `if ! ( commad)` is **part of** the command, thus, it changes the `$?`. So, when I checked `$?` for exit status of `command`, I was wrong. The accepted answer explains this in details.

According to my coding experience, programs return/exit 0 on success and other values on fail. For example, in C, we use `exit 0` to indicate a successful termination. But when I wrote a bash script to determine whether a command succeeded, I find very strange that `0` now means some errors happened and the command fails. For example,

```
if ! (make $1); then
   exit 1
fi
```

**Question** Why the exit status code is 0 when a command fails in BASH?

Comment: Are you talking about the `! (make $1)` test here, or are you talking about something else ? (As for your comment about `scp`, I have run it a few different ways where it fails, and its exit status was 1).

Comment: Short answer: It isn't. If you use `!` to invert it, on the other hand...

Comment: `scp nosuchbox.example.com:nosuchfile.txt . ; echo $?` prints 1 for me.

Comment: Keep in mind that because `0` means success, an `if` statement will branch to the true side on an exit status of 0, and go to the else branch on a nonzero exit status. Perhaps this is what is confusing?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy part of. I figured out why I was confused. I didn't see that the ``if ! `` will change the ``$?`` value.

Comment: @PengZhang, the `!` isn't part of the `if`; it's part of the (compound) command being run, so yes, it changes that command's exit status.

Comment: @PengZhang, one conventional way to write error-handling code that preserves `$?` long enough to emit it: `foo || { rc=$?; echo "foo failed with exit $rc; exit $rc; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim made in this question is false; bash does not use `0` to represent a failed exit.

```
$ make bad; echo $?
make: *** No rule to make target `bad'.  Stop.
2
$ scp badhost:/something .; echo $?
ssh: Could not resolve hostname badhost: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
1
```

Of course, using `!` to invert failure and success will have the effect of making `$?` be 0 following a failure -- but this is explicit and deliberate action.

```
$ ! make bad; echo $?
make: *** No rule to make target `bad'.  Stop.
0
$ ! scp badhost:/something .; echo $?
ssh: Could not resolve hostname badhost: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
0
```

Comment: "bash does not use 0 to represent a successful exit" - it does, and you just proved it. it's just that thinking in terms of "C logic" (0=false) about command exit status is wrong.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath except in arithmetic context: `if ((0)); then echo "I love ponies"; fi`: you won't see what my favorite animal is.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, ...indeed. *facepalm*.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: right. and wrong:) from the manual: `((expression))` "If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1."

Answer (score 0):

The logic, short circuiting of the logic operators `||` and `&&`, negation and everything else is the same in both languages.

The only difference is *what* represents a truth (true, success) and falsity (false, failure).

In C `0` is false and everything else is true. In `bash` exit status context it's the opposite.

`if ! (make $1); then`

should be read as: if `make $1` failed (= it didn't return `0`), then...